# How to do autoplay on click in html5 Video for bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap modal window which is called by a href link.

The modal code is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" onclick="pauseVideo()">&times;</button>
                <div class="iframe-video">
                          <video width='100%' id="video-gpro" src="someVideo.mp4" controls />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

which is called on the click of href link following:

```
<a class="play-button"  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-theVideo="someVideo.mp4"><div class="play-button"></div></a>
```

The problem is I need to autoplay it, after the click happen. But if I write the video tag as autoplay, it comes with autoplay on the page load. But I need the autoplay happen after the click of the 'play-button'.

Please sort me out this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try this, but something like this might work for you...

```
// when the modal is opened...
$('#videoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  // call play() on the <video> DOM element 
  $('#video-gpro')[0].play()
})
```

You can do the same in reverse to pause the video if it continues playing....

```
// when the modal is opened...
$('#videoModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  // call pause() on the <video> DOM element 
  $('#video-gpro')[0].pause()
})
```